# can I rename windows domain controller TLD

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Domain controller server (w2k3) that run a couples of services locally and on the network like share point, Project manager server , ...

Actually  the netbios name is like the domain name for example my domain name is mynetworkdom (without dot TLD)

can I add a TLD to my domain to be like mynetworkdom.net without stop productivity and the other servers continue running right

NB : I have another server as secondary domain controller (backup)
NB : the dns server is in the same Domain controller machine

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a single-label domain name.

You have a couple of choices here:

1. Rename your domain with `rendom.exe`
2. Migrate to a new domain

The best option is probably the second one. SharePoint, Exchange, and the System Center products don't take kindly to being in a domain that's renamed. Grab a copy of the Active Directory Migration Toolkit. It will let you move users, computers, and groups into a new domain that is named properly.

At the risk of shamelessly self-promoting myself, it would seem like you should [read my blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810122929/http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html) about how to properly name your Active Directory.

Comment: if I just add  tld (technically rename my domain name) is the other services like share point, project server and any other AD based server will run properly? however the netbios still the same before renaming and after renaming

Comment: how about this scenario : 1-make a secondary domain controller with same name 2-rename the primary domain controller (add .tld) 3-shutdown the secondary DC 4-if everything running right it's OK if not shutdown the PDC and switch to BDC

Comment: There are no such things as primary domain controllers and backup domain controllers. Those went away with Windows NT. Also, the FQDN of the domain controllers is derived from the FQDN of the domain, but just renaming the DC won't change the name of your AD domain. I think you might be best off bringing in a contractor that has experience in this to help you plan and execute what you're looking for. This is a serious task and you seem be to in over your head.